# datastage parameter for file directory not working

Tags: etl, datastage

I am creating an extract from sequential file.  I created a parameter with the correct file location and when I try to "View Data", it says it can't find the file.  If I hard code the location it finds the file and I am able to "View Data".

example:

`#filedirectory# = aaa/bbb/ccc/`

so my entry for "File" is #filedirectory#filename.txt and this does not work

however, the following does work
`aaa/bbb/ccc/filename.txt`

Any ideas what would cause this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the absolute path. Start with a / and the root directory.

Second point is that the parameter itself does not have "#". The "#" are only needed to reference it - in the Sequential File stage. So name it filedirectory when you define it in the job.

Recommendation:
As filedirectory will probably be used throughout your project I recommand using a ParameteSet.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Those were great suggestions, but didn't solve my problem.  I fixed my issue by browsing to the file, copying that path, and assigning that to the parameter.  It seems casing does matter with file path...  The only difference between the path I had assigned to the parameter and what I pasted in was that one folder name in the path  was all caps.

Comment: Ok that was not reflected in your question  and yes Unix is case sensitive. My recommendation is still valid though

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and it happened I forgot to include the directory parameter before the file parameter. Hope this information helps someone.